# EPR spectrum simulation

Tags: software-recommendations, spectroscopy, open-source

Can anyone recommend code (preferably open-source) for the simulation of EPR spectra from electronic structure calculations?

I found [EasySpin](https://www.easyspin.org):

> EasySpin is an open-source MATLAB toolbox for simulating Electron Paramagnetic Resonance (EPR) spectra

But it requires MATLAB. Are there any good alternatives?

Comment: Many (but not all) MATLAB codes can be run on Octave, which is an open-source alternative to MATLAB. I'm however not sure if EasySpin can be run on Octave

Comment: @wzkchem5 thanks!! I’ll give it a try.

Comment: There appears to exist an Octave-adapted fork, see https://github.com/niconeuman/Easyspin-Octave and [this forum post](https://www.easyspin.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=2775). The fork is not fully up to date, but the [list of compatibility changes](https://github.com/niconeuman/Easyspin-Octave/blob/main/CompatibilityChanges.pdf) could be useful if you want to try to run more recent versions on Octave as well.

Comment: Thanks @Anyon !!

Comment: +1. How did this work out for you? Did you manage to get it working using Octave? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.

Comment: Hi @NikeDattani. I couldn't use the Octave adaptation and ended up getting a Matlab license.

Comment: @AntoniodeOliveira-Filho Sadly Octave hasn't (yet) caught up to MATLAB! I hope that it does soon! Unfortunately too many people are now learning Python instead of MATLAB/Octave now, so interest in developing Octave isn't as great as I'd like it to be. I wonder if [Spinach](http://spindynamics.org/group/?page_id=12) runs better on Octave than EasySpin? In fact I'm even curious whether the MATLAB version of EasySpin is better than the MATLAB version of Spinach. I know the author of Spinach and feel like it's one of the best MATLAB packages in all of computational chemistry!